# FB.XFBML.parse loops and gives thousands of javascript errors

Tags: facebook-like, xfbml

I have a number of dynamically generated like buttons on a site (http://www.thepropaganda.com), and so I use FB.XFBML.parse to generate them all. For some reason the parser always gets into a loop and repeatedly generates "domain and protocol must match" errors as per [FB.SO Question 3577947](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3577947/facebook-gives-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error-in-chr). All the facebook social plugins are created correctly.

I understand what the errors are, and they're not really a problem, other than that there's thousands of them. Funnily enough this doesn't happen at all in incognito.

I'd really like to know what's going on here, as it's a live site for a paying client.

Comment: Did you try setting the channelUrl to a page on your domain? Just asking although I tried that and I'm still getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

No idea why that's occurring but if it doesn't happen in incognito I'm assuming it's something to do with a cookie/session variable.
I would have added this as a comment but I need 50 rep to do it :(